# How to display like and dislike count in Drupal Web Services

Tags: views, services, rating

I'm working with Drupal 7.x, for web services I'm using [service](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) & [services_views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) whereas for voting I'm using [rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) with [votingapi](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) as the dependency.

I'm unable to get the count of positive votes i.e. nothing but **like** and count of negative votes i.e. nothing but **dislike** below attached is my view code:

```
<?php
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'web_services';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Web Services';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  '_story' => '_story',
);

/* Display: List */
$handler = $view->new_display('services', 'List', 'list');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['relationships'] = FALSE;
/* Relationship: File Usage: File */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['node_to_file']['id'] = 'node_to_file';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['node_to_file']['table'] = 'file_usage';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['node_to_file']['field'] = 'node_to_file';
/* Relationship: Content: Vote results */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['id'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['field'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['required'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['votingapi'] = array(
  'value_type' => 'points',
  'tag' => 'thumbs_up_down',
  'function' => 'count',
);
/* Relationship: Content: Votes */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['id'] = 'votingapi_vote';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['field'] = 'votingapi_vote';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['required'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['votingapi'] = array(
  'value_type' => 'points',
  'tag' => 'thumbs_up_down',
);
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['current_user'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = 'ID';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = 'Title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['link_to_node'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Body */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['id'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['table'] = 'field_data_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['field'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['label'] = 'Summary';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['type'] = 'text_trimmed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['settings'] = array(
  'trim_length' => '120',
);
/* Field: File: Path */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uri']['id'] = 'uri';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uri']['table'] = 'file_managed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uri']['field'] = 'uri';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uri']['relationship'] = 'node_to_file';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uri']['label'] = 'mediaURL';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uri']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uri']['empty'] = 'http://esakal/sites/esakal/files/default_images/Sakal_Media_Group_logo.jpg';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uri']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uri']['file_download_path'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Cover Image */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['id'] = 'field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['field'] = 'field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['label'] = 'thumbnailURL';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => 'thumbnail',
  'image_link' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Comment count */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['id'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['table'] = 'node_comment_statistics';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['field'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['label'] = 'numberOfComments';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['label'] = 'CreateDate';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['date_format'] = 'long';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
/* Field: Votes: Value */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['id'] = 'value';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['table'] = 'votingapi_vote';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['field'] = 'value';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['relationship'] = 'votingapi_vote';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['precision'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  '_story' => '_story',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 1;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Appearance Status Tags (field_status_tags) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['id'] = 'field_status_tags_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_status_tags';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['field'] = 'field_status_tags_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_status_tags_tid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['expose']['label'] = 'categoryAppearance';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_status_tags_tid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['expose']['identifier'] = 'categoryAppearance';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['type'] = 'select';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_status_tags_tid']['vocabulary'] = 'appearance_status_tags';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Site Section Tags (field_site_section_tags) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['id'] = 'field_site_section_tags_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_site_section_tags';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['field'] = 'field_site_section_tags_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_site_section_tags_tid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['expose']['label'] = 'categoryID';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_site_section_tags_tid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['expose']['identifier'] = 'categoryID';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['type'] = 'select';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_site_section_tags_tid']['vocabulary'] = 'site_section_tags';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = '-list';
$translatables['web_services'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« first'),
  t('‹ previous'),
  t('next ›'),
  t('last »'),
  t('List'),
  t('File'),
  t('Vote results'),
  t('Votes'),
  t('ID'),
  t('Title'),
  t('Summary'),
  t('mediaURL'),
  t('thumbnailURL'),
  t('numberOfComments'),
  t('.'),
  t(','),
  t('CreateDate'),
  t('Value'),
  t('categoryAppearance'),
  t('categoryID'),
  t('Detail'),
  t('User entity referenced from field_reporter'),
  t('Profile'),
  t('Content'),
  t('twitterHashTag'),
  t('00'),
  t('socialURL'),
  t('ReporterName'),
  t('ReporterEmailID'),
  t('ReporterTwitterHandler'),
  t('categoryName'),
  t('relatedArticles'),
  t('ReportedDate'),
  t('ReporterProfileURL'),
  t('Media'),
  t('mediaID'),
  t('timeStamp'),
  t('caption'),
  t('videoURL'),
  t('mediaType'),
  t('Comment'),
  t('Comments'),
  t('commentorName'),
  t('commentText'),
  t('completeTimeStamp'),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried that module [services_votingapi](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_votingapi) instead of using views It will help achieve our goal

Also [flag_service](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_service) will help you get flags count If you used in your side without having to build custom module or even use views

Comment: services_votingapi looks good, but I'm unable to work with that. Getting 404 after enabling it from the services list. Any suggestion?

Comment: see the recent log messages and read the module docs and api carefully It will work ISA

Comment: OK, so this is the README.txt attached with the module, http://cgit.drupalcode.org/services_votingapi/plain/README.txt. So basically I'm done with the mentioned steps but there isn't an exact document for leveraging this module. Anyways I've got the solution through R&D and I'll add that as the documentation at Drupal.org

Comment: FYI, services_votingapi did the work. Thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: Great news, kindly do upvote.